# tmux capture-pane doesn't print all texts properly but inserts newline after a few characters instead

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I have this script here:

```
tmux send-keys "${@:1}" Enter
sleep 2.5; tmux capture-pane -p -S -32767
```

This script captures the `tmux` pane and prints the output. I noticed that if the `tmux` pane isn't opened, the output would look like this:

```
L 05/15/2018 - 16:07:43
: "thebravelittleMercen
ary<348><[U:1:313493299
]><Blue>" say "!resizem
ytorso"
BOI: !resizemyhands
L 05/15/2018 - 16:07:44
: "BOI<377><[U:1:453920
082]><Red>" say "!resiz
emyhands"
```

In reality, it should look like this:

```
L 05/15/2018 - 16:07:43: "thebravelittleMercenary<348><[U:1:313493299]><Blue>" say "!resizemytorso"
BOI: !resizemyhands
L 05/15/2018 - 16:07:44: "BOI<377><[U:1:453920082]><Red>" say "!resizemyhands"
```

It is worth mentioning that when I do `tmux attach` and capture the pane, the output lines have the same length as my console width: http://i.cubeupload.com/Rp1BEU.png

Comment: Maybe try `capture-pane -J`...

Comment: Oh that worked. I probably skipped through some important stuff in the manual

Comment: In some manual pages the option is buried, so possibly not easy to find either :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output is "wrapped" in the pane, so you'll want to use:

```
capture-pane -J
```

> **-J** joins wrapped lines and preserves
>                trailing spaces at each line's end.

↳ https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/tmux-1.html

Comment: On tmux 3.1c `-J` adds a bunch of trailing spaces to the end of most lines, seems to pad everything to 68 chars on a minimal terminal test with just `echo a`, so it's not ideal either.